# KnockoutJS: Dynamically Insert in a nested observable array by a value of a Key

Tags: knockout.js

I have JSON Object which looks like this:

```
Data: {
    MembershipName:
    Countries: {
                CountryName: "USA"
                States:
                                {
                                  State: "Alabama"
                                       {
                                          Members: {}
                                       } 
                                }
       }
}
```

I wanted to insert inside the "State" observable array with the CountryName "USA".

Right now, I can insert to Countries by:

```
self.Data()[$index].Countries.push(
            new countryViewModel(
                {
                    'CountryName': self.SelectedCountry()
                }
            )
        );
```

But what if instead of using $index, I wanted to insert depending on the value of one of the keys in that array? For this example is WHERE "CountryName" is "USA"?

Comment: `self.Data()[$index]` and `Data: {}` don't work together .. maybe `Data:{[]}` would but that doesn't reflect your (lite) example.. please provide a simplified fiddle so we could continue from there.

Answer (score 0):

solved this using the following approach:

```
self.Data()[$parentIndex].Countries()[$index].States.push(
            new stateViewModel(
                {
                    'State': self.SelectedState()
                }
            )
```